# How to fill up the side of a cylinder using triangles

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create six sides for a cylinder using OpenGL and two triangles for each side. I am currently using wireframe mode, so I can see the triangles that are being used. I finished by code for the cylinderVertices array and the cylinderIndices array, but whenever I run the program, the base comes out perfectly, but the sides are messed up. Is there something wrong with the angles that I am using for the sine and cosine coordinates in my cylinderVertices array or do my indices need fixing in my cylinderIndices array? Maybe someone can help me give the right coordinates. Here is my code:

```
    #include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

// GLM library 
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

int width, height;
const double PI = 3.14159;
const float toRadians = PI / 180.0f;

// Draw Primitive(s)
void draw() {
    GLenum mode = GL_TRIANGLES;

    GLsizei indices = 63;

    glDrawElements(mode, indices, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
}

// Create and Compile Shaders
static GLuint CompileShader(const string& source, GLuint shaderType) {

    // Create Shader Object
    GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    const char* src = source.c_str();

    // Attach source code to Shader object
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &src, nullptr);

    // Compile Shader
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    // Return ID of Compiled shader
    return shaderID;
}

// Create Program Object
static GLuint CreateShaderProgram(const string& vertexShader, const string& fragmentShader) {

    // Compile vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShaderComp = CompileShader(vertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    // Compile fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShaderComp = CompileShader(fragmentShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Create program object
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    // Attch vertex and fragment shaders to program object
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderComp);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderComp);

    // Link shaders to create executable
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Delete compiled vertex and fragment shaders
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderComp);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderComp);

    // Return Shader Program
    return shaderProgram;
}

int main(void) {

    width = 640; height = 480;

    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Main Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        cout << "Error!" << endl;

    GLfloat cylinderVertices[] = {

    // Base of the cylinder     
    // Triangle One                                     // Color
    0.0,                  0.0,                  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 0  red
    cos(  0 * toRadians), sin(  0 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 1  green
    cos( 60 * toRadians), sin( 60 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 2  blue
    // Part of Triangle Two
    cos(120 * toRadians), sin(120 * toRadians), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 3  purple
    // Part of Triangle Three
    cos(180 * toRadians), sin(180 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 4  greem
    // Part of Triangle Four
    cos(240 * toRadians), sin(240 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 5  blue
    // Part of Triangle Five
    cos(300 * toRadians), sin(300 * toRadians), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 6  purple
    // Part of Triangle Six
    cos(360 * toRadians), sin(360 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  // Vertex 7  green

    // Sides of the cylinder
    // Part of Triangle Seven
    cos(  0 * toRadians), sin(  0 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 8 red
    // Part of Triangle Eight
    cos(  45 * toRadians), sin(  45 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 9 green
    // Part of Triangle Nine
    cos(  60 * toRadians), sin(  60 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 10 blue
    // Part of Triangle Ten
    cos(  105 * toRadians), sin(  105 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 11 purple
    // Part of Triangle Eleven
    cos(  120 * toRadians), sin(  120 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 12 red
    // Part of Triangle Twelve
    cos(  165 * toRadians), sin(  165 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 13 green
    // Part of Triangle Thirteen
    cos(  180 * toRadians), sin(  180 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 14 blue
    // Part of Triangle Fourteen
    cos(  225 * toRadians), sin(  225 * toRadians), 2.0, 1,0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 15 purple
    // Part of Triangle Fifteen
    cos(  240 * toRadians), sin(  240 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 // Vertex 16 red
    };

    // Define element indices 
    GLubyte cylinderIndices[] = {
        0,1,2,
        0,2,3,
        0,3,4,
        0,4,5,
        0,5,6,
        0,6,7,
        1,2,8,
        2,8,9,
        3,2,10,
        2,9,10,
        3,10,11,
        3,4,11,
        4,11,12,
        4,5,12,
        5,12,13,
        5,6,13,
        6,13,14,
        5,6,14,
        5,6,15,
        6,1,15,
        1,6,8
    };

    // Enable Depth Buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Wireframe mode
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    GLuint VBO, EBO, VAO;

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); // Create VBO and returns ID
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO); // Create EBO

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); // Create VAO
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); // Select VBO and activate buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO); // Select EBO

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cylinderVertices), cylinderVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Load vertex attributes
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cylinderIndices), cylinderIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Load indices attributes

    // Specify attributes location and layout to GPU
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Color attribute location and layout
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Vertex shader source code
    string vertexShaderSource =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec4 aColor;"
        "out vec4 oColor;"
        "uniform mat4 model;"
        "uniform mat4 view;"
        "uniform mat4 projection;"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vPosition;"
        "oColor = aColor;"
        "}\n";

    // Fragment shader source code
    string fragmentShaderSource =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "in vec4 oColor;"
        "out vec4 fragColor;"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "fragColor = oColor;"
        "}\n";

    // Creating Shader Program
    GLuint shaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        // Resize window and graphics simultaneously
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // Render here
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use Shader Program exe and select VAO before drawing
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram); // Call Shader per-frame when updating attributes

        // Declare identity matrix 
        glm::mat4 modelMatrix(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 viewMatrix(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 projectionMatrix(1.0f);

        // Initialize transforms
        modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

        // I increased the third argument from -3.0f to -6.0f to make the object smaller
        viewMatrix = glm::translate(viewMatrix, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f));
        // I changed up somme of the arguments, so the object would tilt left instead of toward me
        viewMatrix = glm::rotate(viewMatrix, 45.0f * toRadians, glm::vec3(-0.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f));

        projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f * toRadians, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // Select uniform shader and variable
        GLuint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
        GLuint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        GLuint projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");

        // Pass transform to Shader

        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO); // User-defined VAO must be called before draw

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            glm::mat4 modelMatrix(1.0f);

            glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));

            // Draw primitive(s)
            draw();

        }

        // Unbind Shader exe and VOA after drawing per frame
        glBindVertexArray(0); // In case different VAO will be used after
        glUseProgram(0); // In case different shader will be used after

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you keep going on and draw all the other sides, what stop you?

Comment: you can draw it on paper and see what's correct coordinate, it's not too hard with 6-side cylinder.

Comment: btw index 012 is clockwise while 128 is ccw, it'd not draw correctly with backface culling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

```
    GLfloat cylinderVertices[] = {

// Base of the cylinder     
// Triangle One                                     // Color
0.0,                  0.0,                  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 0  red
cos(  0 * toRadians), sin(  0 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 1  green
cos( 60 * toRadians), sin( 60 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 2  blue
// Part of Triangle Two
cos(120 * toRadians), sin(120 * toRadians), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 3  purple
// Part of Triangle Three
cos(180 * toRadians), sin(180 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 4  greem
// Part of Triangle Four
cos(240 * toRadians), sin(240 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 5  blue
// Part of Triangle Five
cos(300 * toRadians), sin(300 * toRadians), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 6  purple
// Part of Triangle Six
cos(360 * toRadians), sin(360 * toRadians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  // Vertex 7  green

// Sides of the cylinder
// Part of Triangle Seven
cos(  0 * toRadians), sin(  0 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 8 red
// Part of Triangle Eight
cos(  60 * toRadians), sin(  60 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 9 green
// Part of Triangle Nine
cos(  120 * toRadians), sin(  120 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 10 blue
// Part of Triangle Ten
cos(  180 * toRadians), sin(  180 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Vertex 11 purple
// Part of Triangle Eleven
cos(  240 * toRadians), sin(  240 * toRadians), 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 12 red
// Part of Triangle Twelve
cos(  300 * toRadians), sin(  300 * toRadians), 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Vertex 13 green

};

// Define element indices 
GLubyte cylinderIndices[] = {
    // Bottom base
    0,1,2,
    0,2,3,
    0,3,4,
    0,4,5,
    0,5,6,
    0,6,7,
    // Sides
    1,2,8,
    2,9,8,
    2,3,9,
    3,10,9,
    3,4,10,
    4,11,10,
    5,11,4,
    5,12,11,
    5,6,12,
    6,13,12,
    6,1,13,
    1,8,13
};
```